# Manipulate object with reduce

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, reduce

Here's my input `{field1: {field2:'123', field3:{field4:'123'}}}`

The goal is `{field1: {update: {field2:'123', field3: {update: {field4:'123'}}`

Here's what I have tried

```
function updateDictHelper(obj) {
 Object.entries(obj).reduce((updateClause = {}, [key, value]) => {
  if (typeof value !== 'object') {
    return {... updateClause, [key]: value}
  } else {
    return {... updateClause, [key]: {update: updateDictHelper(value)}}
  }


 })
}
```

However, I can get it to work no matter what. I am quite new to java/typescript and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: You missed `return` in front of `Object.entries(obj)`

Comment: Also, you should use the initial value of `.reduce()` (ie: second argument), rather than providing a default value `= {}`, otherwise you will skip the first iteration of your entries (which isn't good if you only have one value in your entries array)

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you please provide an example?

Comment: Please be aware that in JS a "dictionary" doesn't exist. The closest alternatives are Objects, Maps, WeakMaps, etc.

Comment: Note the lack of space between the spread ... and the updateClause: `const updateDictHelper = obj => Object.entries(obj).reduce((updateClause, [key, value]) =>  typeof value === 'object' ? { ...updateClause, [key]: { update: updateDictHelper(value) } : { ...updateClause, [key]: value }},  {});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues, the first is that your `updateDirectHelper` doesn't `return` anything. While you have a `return` inside of this function, it's actually nested inside of the `reduce`'s callback function `(updateClause, [key, value]) => {`, not the `updateDictHelper` itself.

Your other issue is how you're providing a default value for `acc`. Reduce natively supports [an optional second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#syntax) which will act as the initial value for `acc`.

```js
reduce(callbackFn, initialValue)
```

It is best practice to always provide one if you can. If you don't include it, `.reduce()` will essentially skip the first invocation of the callback and begin by calling the callback function with `acc` set to the first value in your array, and the second argument to the second value in your array. If your array only has one value, such as in your case, then that single value is what is returned from the `.reduce()` call, and your callback function for `.reduce()` is never invoked:

```js
const arrayWithOneElement = [1];
const res = arrayWithOneElement.reduce(() => {
  console.log("I never run");
}); // Notice no second argument
console.log(res);
```

To avoid all of this, you can instead pass a second argument as an empty object, which will be the starting value of `acc`:

```js
function updateDictHelper(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((updateClause, [key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value !== 'object') {
      return {...updateClause, [key]: value}
    } else {
      return {...updateClause, [key]: {update: updateDictHelper(value)}}
    }
  }, {});
}

console.log(updateDictHelper({field1: {field2:'123', field3:{field4:'123'}}}));
```

I would personally do this with a newer method, [Object.fromEntiries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), which will build the object for you. Saves you having to worry about dealing with `.reduce()` with this approach:

```js
function updateDictHelper(obj) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => [
    key, 
    Object(value) === value ? {update: updateDictHelper(value)} : value
  ]));
}

console.log(updateDictHelper({field1: {field2:'123', field3:{field4:'123'}}}));
```